# can match() have a range included in R?

Tags: r, match

I am trying to use `match()` in R to find any matching values within a certain interval. For example:

```
v <- c(2.2, 2.4, 4.3, 1.3, 4.5, 6.8, 0.9)
match(2.4, v)
```

gives me all the locations where 2.4 occurs in `v`, but what if I wanted to give a range for all possible matches? For example 2.4 +/- 0.2?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: `which(abs(v - 2.4) < 0.2)`?

Comment: Be aware that `match` returns only the first argument that match. Maybe `which` can be better for you even though with the code provided here both have the same result (with a  slightly different syntax).

Comment: Also maybe `data.table::between(v, 2.2, 2.6, incbounds = FALSE)`

Comment: @docendodiscimus that is a very succinct way to solve the problem, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In that case, I would use subsetting:

```
v[v>2.2 & v<2.6]
```

or

```
which(v>2.2 & v<2.6)
```

depending on if you want the values or the index

Answer (score 2):

This is another option:

```
which(findInterval(v, c(-.2, .2) + 2.4) == 1)
[1] 1 2
```

`findInterval(v, c(-.2, .2) + 2.4)` gives you `1 1 2 0 2 2 0`, where 1 means the element is inside the interval, 0 means it's to the left, and 2 means to the right.